# Fetching Data as a Json format in react native return error when mapping data

Tags: react-native

The error returned is : `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'json.map')` ,knowing that my api has multiple data.
The code i use to fetch data is :

```
CheckifReadLater = async () => {
    const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
    const isLoggedIn = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
    if (isLoggedIn == 1 && username) {
      await fetch(Config.backendAPI+`/readlater.php?username=${username}&select`)
        .then((response) => {
          reactotron.log("Response : ",response);
          response.json();
        })
        .then((json) => {
          json.map((product, index) => {
            if (product.id == this.props.product.id) {
              this.setState({
                isReadLater: true,
              })
            }
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => reactotron.log('This is the error: ',error))
    }
    reactotron.log("Readlater : ",this.state.isReadLater);

  }
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the `response.json();` on the first `.then` function for it to be available on the next `.then`.

Do this:

```
 await fetch(Config.backendAPI+`/readlater.php?username=${username}&select`)
        .then((response) => {
          reactotron.log("Response : ",response);
          // update your code here
          return response.json();
        })
```